# Store UmbracoIdentity data in SQL Server

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have implemented Umbraco using UmbracoIdentity for membership and everything was going fine until I deployed my solution to an Azure Web App. On azure I am getting permission errors because UmbracoIdentity is using a SQL Server CE database stored in the `App_Data` folder.

For reference the error I am getting is:

> Exception type: SqlCeException
>   There is a file sharing violation. A different process might be using the file. [ ...\wwwroot\App_Data\UmbracoIdentity.sdf ]

My Umbraco data is being stored in an SQL database and I would like to store my UmbracoIdentity membership data here as well. I would appreciate any help in how to setup SQL Server as the user store for membership data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the [IExternalLoginStore.cs](https://github.com/Shazwazza/UmbracoIdentity/blob/master/src/UmbracoIdentity/IExternalLoginStore.cs) interface and then configure the application to use it.  It should be fairly simple to implement as you can use the [SQL Server CE implementation as an example](https://github.com/Shazwazza/UmbracoIdentity/blob/master/src/UmbracoIdentity/ExternalLoginStore.cs).  I've done one for Azure Table Storage - you can check the Readme at https://github.com/alindgren/UmbracoIdentity.AzureLoginStore to get an idea of how to configure the app to use a custom external login store (which for me was the least obvious part).